# Section Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have achieved the section navigation.In that i am facing one probelm we have a header of height 120px with position:fixed .Since section navigation always move the section to the top of the window .Some of the content become hidden inside the 120px header.For that i made padding as 120px.but it looks odd since each and every section has the gap of 120px makes the section ugly.how can i make the content visible without adding the padding :120px.

> ### -----------------------------------------------> on click of navigation content header came here and become hidden
>
> ### Header - 120px
>
> ---
>
> ### Content

just like this it is happening - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.4
Since i am using fixed header.Content is hihding inside the Header

**Updated - Added Fiddler**

Whats happening : http://jsfiddle.net/rg46D/

How i fix that : http://jsfiddle.net/rg46D/1/

What i want to remove : Adding the padding top 80px;creating more space between the content.how to make the content visible without adding the padding top 80px

```
 <div id="Home" style="background-color: lightblue; height: 600px;padding-top:80px">
```

Comment: Post your code. a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will be better

Comment: difficult to imagine your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/CvLZL/

Comment: @Era,@Amarnath Balasubramanian : Added fiddler link.Kindly look into it

Comment: @hsakarp : cant you provide padding only to your `id=Home` via css? http://jsfiddle.net/rg46D/2/

Comment: providing only to home fix the home alone.If you click on link or about again the header is hiding inside the header - Thanks.

Comment: @Era : i am not sure how they done.but they have proper spacing in place.Want to achieve something like this - http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2

Comment: Well I guess in this case jQuery might be useful. using which you can calculate how much space you want from top http://jsfiddle.net/hd2Kn/

Comment: Thanks @PravinVaichal .Exactly that what i wanted.

Comment: Cool It helps I will post it as answer so it might be helpful to others as well Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess in this case jQuery might be useful. using which you can calculate how much space you want from top

```
$('.menu a').click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var getEle = $(this).attr('href'); 
    var navHeight = 72 // if you want you may calculate it dynamically using jQuery it would be better

    $("body, html").animate({
        scrollTop: ($(getEle).position().top)-navHeight
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap a div before your section with padding:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="Home" style="background-color: lightblue; height: 600px;">HOme</div>
    <div id="Links" style="background-color: lightgray; height: 600px;">Links</div>
    <div id="about" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 600px;">about</div>
</div>
```

and provide padding to this class:

```
.wrapper {
    padding-top:80px;
}
```

Add Js:

```
 $('.menu a').click(function (e) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.wrapper div').css({
        paddingTop: '0',
        marginTop: '0'
    });
    $(link).css({
        paddingTop: '80px',
        marginTop: '-80px'
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hd2Kn/3/)**

Add this `.wrapper` div in all your inner pages to get the desired result.

Comment: i am sorry, if you click on about, again the header is hiding inside the header.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did that by dynamically adding the padding-top on click event and removing it when scroll event fires.

calling this onclick :

```
$('#id').css('padding-top','100px')
```

and setting a flag to true;

on scroll event checking for the flag and changing it back to the

```
$('#id').css('padding-top','0px')
```